# Category Image / getImageUrl() is empty

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, category, template, image

In back end I can see the category has an image but if I try to show it in a template it is empty:

```
  $_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
  $_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl();
```

**Why is `$_imgUrl` empty?**

Template file is `\app\design\frontend\default\kemweb\template\page`

`var_dump($_category)` looks like this:

```
`$_category` does contain the correct item (entity_id checked). Same code worked on other magento installation. Any clue what is going wrong here?

 object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category)#96 (23) {
  ["_eventPrefix":protected]=>
  string(16) "catalog_category"
  ["_eventObject":protected]=>
  string(8) "category"
  ["_cacheTag":protected]=>
  string(16) "catalog_category"
  ["_useFlatResource":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["_designAttributes":"Mage_Catalog_Model_Category":private]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(13) "custom_design"
    [1]=>
    string(18) "custom_design_from"
    [2]=>
    string(16) "custom_design_to"
    [3]=>
    string(11) "page_layout"
    [4]=>
    string(20) "custom_layout_update"
    [5]=>
    string(24) "custom_apply_to_products"
  }
  ["_treeModel":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_defaultValues":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["url_path"]=>
    string(13) "schenken.html"
  }
  ["_storeValuesFlags":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["url_path"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
  ["_lockedAttributes":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_isDeleteable":protected]=>
  bool(true)
  ["_isReadonly":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["_resourceName":protected]=>
  string(16) "catalog/category"
  ["_resource":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_resourceCollectionName":protected]=>
  string(27) "catalog/category_collection"
  ["_dataSaveAllowed":protected]=>
  bool(true)
  ["_isObjectNew":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["_data":protected]=>
  array(34) {
    ["store_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["entity_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["entity_type_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["attribute_set_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["parent_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2013-06-19 11:29:11"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2013-07-02 09:56:14"
    ["path"]=>
    string(5) "1/2/3"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["level"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["children_count"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Schenken"
    ["url_key"]=>
    string(8) "schenken"
    ["meta_title"]=>
    NULL
    ["display_mode"]=>
    string(8) "PRODUCTS"
    ["custom_design"]=>
    NULL
    ["page_layout"]=>
    NULL
    ["url_path"]=>
    string(13) "schenken.html"
    ["thumbnail"]=>
    string(16) "cat_schenken.jpg"
    ["is_active"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["include_in_menu"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["landing_page"]=>
    NULL
    ["is_anchor"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["custom_use_parent_settings"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["custom_apply_to_products"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["description"]=>
    NULL
    ["meta_keywords"]=>
    NULL
    ["meta_description"]=>
    NULL
    ["custom_layout_update"]=>
    NULL
    ["available_sort_by"]=>
    NULL
    ["custom_design_from"]=>
    NULL
    ["custom_design_to"]=>
    NULL
    ["filter_price_range"]=>
    NULL
    ["path_ids"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "1"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "2"
      [2]=>
      string(1) "3"
    }
  }
  ["_hasDataChanges":protected]=>
  bool(true)
  ["_origData":protected]=>
  array(33) {
    ["store_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["entity_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["entity_type_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["attribute_set_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["parent_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2013-06-19 11:29:11"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2013-07-02 09:56:14"
    ["path"]=>
    string(5) "1/2/3"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["level"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["children_count"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Schenken"
    ["url_key"]=>
    string(8) "schenken"
    ["meta_title"]=>
    NULL
    ["display_mode"]=>
    string(8) "PRODUCTS"
    ["custom_design"]=>
    NULL
    ["page_layout"]=>
    NULL
    ["url_path"]=>
    string(13) "schenken.html"
    ["thumbnail"]=>
    string(16) "cat_schenken.jpg"
    ["is_active"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["include_in_menu"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["landing_page"]=>
    NULL
    ["is_anchor"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["custom_use_parent_settings"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["custom_apply_to_products"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["description"]=>
    NULL
    ["meta_keywords"]=>
    NULL
    ["meta_description"]=>
    NULL
    ["custom_layout_update"]=>
    NULL
    ["available_sort_by"]=>
    NULL
    ["custom_design_from"]=>
    NULL
    ["custom_design_to"]=>
    NULL
    ["filter_price_range"]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["_idFieldName":protected]=>
  string(9) "entity_id"
  ["_isDeleted":protected]=>
  bool(false)
  ["_oldFieldsMap":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_syncFieldsMap":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see that only the thumbnail attribute has a value (cat_schenken.jpg). In magento admin you can upload a category image and a category thumbnail image. So you probably uploaded only the thumbnail image and not the main image.

Try to use Zend_Debug::dump($_category->getData()) to have a better view of the category's attributes.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you don't even have the image attribute set correctly, `getImageUrl` needs this:

```
public function getImageUrl()
{
    $url = false;
    if ($image = $this->getImage()) {
        $url = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$image;
    }
    return $url;
}
```

According to the var_dump there is something wrong with the category model, usually there should the `$_data['image']` attribute set to something.

Are you sure you don't mix image and thumbnail up? And did you modify something in the database? Like the attribute-group relation? Because that might cause your problems.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue on my Magento 1.9.2.1 build. But I found (weirdly) the image URL was not returned when using **getChildrenCategories()**. My answer was to return the image using **getCollection()** on the model instead like so:

```
    $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);
    if (isset($_cat) && !empty($_cat) && is_object($_cat)) {
        // Create category collection for children
        $childrenCollection = $_cat->getCollection();
        // Only get child categories of parent cat
        $childrenCollection->addIdFilter($_cat->getChildren());
        // Only get active categories
        $childrenCollection->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1);
        // Add base attributes
        $childrenCollection->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('all_children')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('is_anchor')
                ->setOrder('position', Varien_Db_Select::SQL_ASC)
                ->joinUrlRewrite();
        // Add Image 
        $childrenCollection->addAttributeToSelect('image');
        if (count($childrenCollection) > 0) {
            foreach($childrenCollection as $subcat) {
                if ($subcat->getIsActive()) {
                    $subcatName = $subcat->getName();
                    $subcatUrl = $subcat->getUrl();
                    $img = $subcat->getImage();
                    $subcatImgUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/' . $img;

                    if (!empty($subcatName) && !empty($subcatUrl)) {
                        $html .= '<li class="brand ' . $className . '">';
                        $html .=    '<a href="' . $subcatUrl . '" title="' . $subcatName . '">';
                        $html .=        '<img src="' . $subcatImgUrl . '" alt="' . $subcatName . '" />';
                        $html .=    '</a>';
                        $html .= '</li>';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

PandaWebStudio's answer really helped to debug the situation so thank you for that.

Answer (score 2):

As per as your var dump registry variable does not contain the field image.

First you need to check `getImage()` give value or not

In [thebod answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/5356/4564)  already mention that `getImageUrl()`  will give value whenever image field of category have any value.

Here in this question, The object of category `does not contain`  field **image**  that `getImageUrl() does  not give` result.

May be this category Eav Attribute (image) does not exit  database.

**For checking this attribute in system,you can try below Mysql  query**

```
SELECT attribute_code
FROM eav_attribute
WHERE entity_type_id
IN (

SELECT entity_type_id
FROM eav_entity_type
WHERE entity_type_code =  'catalog_category'
)  and attribute_code ='image'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this to get category image url....

```
<?php $child= Mage:getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentcategory()->getId();
 $imagesrc= Mage:getModel('catalog/category')->load($child)->getimageUrl(); 
 echo $imagesrc; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried following so that it does not affect performance and you need to call the category model seprately

Open in root of magento 2.2

/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Category.php

On line750ish

Add

```
->addAttributeToSelect(
    'image'
)
```

or replace function

```
 /**
     * Return child categories
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection
     */
    public function getChildrenCategories($category)
    {
        $collection = $category->getCollection();
        /* @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection */
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect(
            'url_key'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'image'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'name'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'all_children'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'is_anchor'
        )->addAttributeToFilter(
            'is_active',
            1
        )->addIdFilter(
            $category->getChildren()
        )->setOrder(
            'position',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Select::SQL_ASC
        )->joinUrlRewrite();

        return $collection;
    }
```