# Can't get category images to show up!

Tags: image, category, xml

I've been stuck with this for few day's now and can't understand why the category image is not retrieved by magento.

I've added this `page_header.phtml` to the `template/page/html` folder with the following html:

```
    <?php
    $_helper    = Mage::helper('catalog/output');
    $_category  = Mage::registry('current_category');
    $_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()
?>
<?php
    if (!$_imgUrl){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
    $(".top-container").addClass("no-image");
});
</script>
<?php
    }
?>
<div class="bgback" style="<?php if($_imgUrl): ?>background-image: url(<?php echo $_imgUrl; ?>);<?php endif; ?>">
    <div class="container page-header-area">
        <div class="left-area">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml("breadcrumbs"); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="category-top-title">
            <h1><?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="zn_header_bottom_style"></div>
```

Then went to the `local.xml` and added this:

```
    <catalog_category_view>
    <reference name="top.container">
        <block type="core/template" name="page.header" template="page/html/page_header.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_view>
```

It show's up correctly on the category pages, but the issue is that the image is not being displayed and I can't figure out why.

The folder's on the server `media` and `var` has 777 permisions. The image is uploaded in the backend. Did I forget something?

Thanks guys,

Comment: Arturas Strazdas,is this displayed all pages?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Category Image / getImageUrl() is empty](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5344/category-image-getimageurl-is-empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using this step you can display  category menu into navigation menu bar.

http://www.h-o.nl/blog/using_category_images_in_your_magento_navigation/

Comment: or $_imgHtml   = '';
        if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
            $_imgHtml = '<img src="'.$_imgUrl.'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$_category->getName().'" />';
            $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
        }

Comment: Could you please show where shoud I put this line? I'm quite new to developing magento and I don't understand exactly where should I put this. Thanks

Comment: check this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539210/displaying-category-image-in-navigation-menu-in-magento

Comment: When I replace the PHP with the one provided in the answer i get an error: `Call to a member function getImageUrl() on a non-object in`

Comment: from this you can get Image url Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId())->getImageUrl();

Comment: Now I get this: `Call to a member function getId() on a non-objec`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16999/discussion-between-arturas-strazdas-and-anisha-shaikh).

Comment: It is simple just you  have to fetch all categories apply foreach from that categories u cant id .. load Model of category from that Id ..